# Reload using JQuery

Tags: php, ajax, reload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server Side Reload Initiation on Ajax Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917709/server-side-reload-initiation-on-ajax-call)

How do I properly reload the index.php file after an AJAX Call?

Comment: um... php or javascript? after ur javascript call, you can use window.location.href = new_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  not sure, if i understand your problem.
Why don't you reload page on ajax response status?

Example: json response, with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: ...,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
      if (res.status == 1) {
        // do redirect, user is logged in
        window.location = 'b2e.htm';
      } else {
        // login failed
      }
    },
    parsererror: function(res) {
      // login failed
    },
    error: function(doc) {
      // login failed
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

php script:

```
<?php
$logged_in = false;

// your login script

if ($logged_in == true) {
  echo '{"status": 1}';
} else {
  echo '{"status": 0}';
}
?>
```